# How can I use @AutoService in a project in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

My *build.gradle* file is

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1'
}
```

According to `gradle dependencies`, all of compileClasspath, implementation, runtimeClasspath, testCompileClasspath, and testRuntimeClasspath include *com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.1*.

My source file is

```java
package demo;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;

@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class Library extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latest();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                           RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Because [an official example](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/main/service) of AutoService doesn't `import` it, I've also tried several times building a version of my file without the `import com.google.auto.service.AutoService` line.

In any case, `gradle build` always fails, giving me the error

> ```
> error: cannot find symbol
> @AutoService(Processor.class)
>  ^
>   symbol: class AutoService
> 2 errors
> ```

And when I include the `import ...AutoService` I also have the additional error

> ```
> error: package com.google.auto.service does not exist
> import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
> ```

How am I meant to be able to build this project?

My `gradle -version` is 8.1.1, and its JVM is 20.0.1.

---

I've just tested again from a totally fresh project:

```
mkdir demo
cd demo
gradle init # type of project library, everything else default
# replace ./lib/src/main/java/demo/Library.java with the second code block
# make ./build.gradle and make it the first code block
gradle build
```

This still throws the same errors

```
> Task :lib:compileJava FAILED
demo/lib/src/main/java/demo/Library.java:16: error: package com.google.auto.service does not exist
import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
                              ^
demo/lib/src/main/java/demo/Library.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
@AutoService(Processor.class)
 ^
  symbol: class AutoService
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to successfully build the following code. `Gradle` version: 8.0, `java` version: 11

If you did `gradle init` with project `library` type, you need to add dependencies to `lib/build.gradle` file

Comment: Is the only difference that you added `annotationProcessor`? Can you build successfully without that configuration?

Comment: I've got gradle 8.1.1, openjdk 20.0.1

Comment: Without `annotationProcessor` it built successfully. If you are using IntelliJ IDEA it might be a problem with its caches, try refresh them.

Comment: I'm just using gradle CLI

Comment: Why does yours build successfully yet mine does not when they look identical

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76496951/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @minseong Did you also do `gradle init` with project type library ?

Comment: @PeterMortensen If you did `gradle init` with project `library` type, you need to add `dependencies` to `lib/build.gradle` file.

Answer (score -1):

The location of `build.gradle` is in `lib`, not top-level (i.e. it should not be sibling to `settings.gradle`)

Add your dependencies to `lib/build.gradle`